# Resultset mapper or formatter in Cakephp 3

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I have 2 Collections/ Result sets the first one is `products` and second one is `sizes`

```
"products": [
                            {
                                "category_id": 5,
                                "id": 5,
                                "code": "A",
                                "name": "Pizzabrot",
                                "description": "",
                                "product_prices": [
                                    {
                                        "product_id": 5,
                                        "price": 2.5,
                                        "size_id": 15
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "product_id": 5,
                                        "price": 3.5,
                                        "size_id": 16
                                    }
                                ]
                            },
                            {
                                "category_id": 5,
                                "id": 6,
                                "code": "B",
                                "name": "Pizzabrot mit Knoblauch",
                                "description": "",
                                "product_prices": [
                                    {
                                        "product_id": 6,
                                        "price": 3,
                                        "size_id": 15
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "product_id": 6,
                                        "price": 4,
                                        "size_id": 16
                                    }
                                ]
                            }]
```

AND

```
"sizes": [
                        {
                            "id": 15,
                            "name": "Klein",
                            "category_id": 5
                        },
                        {
                            "id": 16,
                            "name": "Gro\u00df",
                            "category_id": 5
                        }
                    ]
```

I want to replace every `product_prices.size_id` with it's name from `sizes` Collection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can see it would probably be better to associate `ProductPrices` and `Sizes` and fetch them with your `Products`.

If this does not fit your needs for some reason, you could find the `sizes` by using a `find('list')` (see [Docs](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/retrieving-data-and-resultsets.html#finding-key-value-pairs)) like this:

```
$query = $this->Sizes->find('list', [
    'keyField' => 'id',
    'valueField' => 'name'
]);
$sizes = $query->toArray();
```

Then loop through the `products` and its `product_prices` and do something like.

```
$product_price->size_id = $sizes[$product_price->size_id];
```

Please prefer the first solution. ;-)